# An integral involving the logarithm of the Gamma function

Tags: integration

Evaluate

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log \Gamma(0.25 + 0.5it) + \log \Gamma(0.25 - 0.5it) }{0.25 + t^2} \mathrm{d}t$$

where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. In my attempt, i applied the well-known Stirling approximation for $\Gamma$, but i'm not quite sure if the approach is correct.

Comment: Wolfram Dev Platform says it doesn't converge on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, it seems you made a mistake somehow in using Wolfram, because the integrand is  $ O\Bigg( \frac{\log t}{t^2} \Bigg)$ by the Stirling approximation.

Comment: All I know is the code `Integrate[(Log[Gamma[1/4+I t/2]]+Log[Gamma[1/4-I t/2]])/(1/4+t^2),{t,-Infinity,Infinity}]` produced the error message `Integral of <function> does not converge on {-infinity,infinity}`. The Wolfram Dev Platform is not omniscient, and it sometimes gets things wrong. However, I'm fairly confident that the code I put in matches your integral.

Comment: `NIntegrate` doesn't do any better, by the way.